# Functions in class in python compile correctly but cannot execute

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to implement the function for reading CSV files in class.

```
class input_data:
    path = ''
    start = 0
    total = 0
    datas = []
    labels = []
    def __init__(self,p):
        self.path = p
    def read_csv(self):
        print(self.path)
        print("hello")


path1='../generate_data/train_data/train_data.csv'
test=input_data('../generate_data/train_data/train_data.csv')
test.read_csv
```

The above code compiles normally, but there is no output when executed.
What is the reason for this?

Comment: Calling a method requires `()`

Answer (score 2):

You have to call a method: `read_csv()`:

Don't use class attributes as instance attributes.

```
class InputData:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        self.start = 0
        self.total = 0
        self.datas = []
        self.labels = []

    def read_csv(self):
        print(self.path)
        print("hello")


path1 = '../generate_data/train_data/train_data.csv'
test = InputData(path1)
test.read_csv()
```

Answer (score 2):

put `()` at the and of the method calling...

```
class input_data:
        path = ''
        start = 0
        total = 0
        datas = []
        labels = []
        def __init__(self,p):
            self.path = p
        def read_csv(self):
            print(self.path)
            print("hello")


    path1='../generate_data/train_data/train_data.csv'
    test=input_data(path1)
    test.read_csv()
```